# iOS: Check if coredata object still exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a problem with two different view controllers. Each one is in a tab bar of my app. And one view controller influences the other one. In my tab bar item 1 (view controller 1) I edit all my database objects. You can add, delete and edit entities in my database there.

In view controller 2, you can select these entities and add subcategories to these entities and edit them as well. But if you are within a certain entity in view controller 2, switch back to view controller 1, delete that entity and switch back to view controller 2, my app crashes. Of course, because the model of this view controller (the just deleted entity) doesn't exist anymore. So how can I check for that in my viewWillAppear? This doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(!self.myEntity){
        self.isNotExistingAnymore = YES;
        NSLog(@"YES;");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` has a `isDeleted` method that returns `YES` if the object
has been marked for deletion in the managed object context.

If the context has been saved so that the object is actually deleted from the
persistent store, then its `managedObjectContext` method returns `nil`.

So this covers both situations:

```
if (self.myObject.isDeleted || self.myObject.managedObjectContext == nil) ...
```

Comment: but if I read the docs correctly it says: "returns a boolean indicating if the receiver will be deleted during the next save". But I save in all my view controllers when the view enters the background. So when view controller 2 reappears, it's model has been already deleted and saved in view controller 1. Will this anyway work in all cases?

Comment: I think this covers both cases (if saved and not yet saved, am I correct?): if([self.myEntity isDeleted] || ![((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:self.myEntity.objectID error:NULL]){

    }

Comment: @MichiZH: That should work. See updated answer for an alternative that worked for me in similar situations.